# В чем преимущество Python модуля - fileinput?

Tags: python, linux, unix, администрирование

Вопрос со стороны прикладного программирования рабочих скриптов под *nix системы.

До недавнего времени использовал стандартную конструкцию чтения файлов:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    with_open_open = f.read() # f.readline(), f.readlines(), ...
```

Нашел в комментариях русского СО сообщества упоминание модуля `fileinput` за года 3 ни разу о нем ни где ни читал.

Вопрос: какие случаи использования этого модуля - оправданы и когда стоит избегать его использование?

Comment: если примеры интересны, для каких задач можно использовать этот модуль, то вот [мои ответы, использующие fileinput](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fileinput+user%3A23044) — можно заголовки прочитать, чтобы общее представление получить  и почитать код для интересных вам случаев.

Comment: @jfs Я из вашего поста и узнал про него. Спасибо ознакомлюсь.

Comment: одним предложением: fileinput реализует [Unix filter pattern](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch11s06.html#id2957637). В perl это реализуется с помощью diamond оператора `<>`. Чтобы прочувствовать  чем фильтры примечательны всю книгу по ссылке может быть необходимо прочесть и иметь опыт с такими примерами [McIlroy's pipeline, которая Knuth пример реализует](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/12/more-shell-less-egg/)

Answer (score 1):

Из [описания модуля](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html):

> This module implements a helper class and functions to quickly write a
>   loop over standard input or a list of files. If you just want to read
>   or write one file see `open()`.

Т.е. все преимущества данного модуля открываются когда надо обрабатывать потоковый стандартный ввод (STDIN) или сразу несколько файлов. Для работы с единственным файлом разработчики советуют обратиться к `open()`...

Также данный модуль позволяет реализовывать фильтрацию / обработку файлов "по месту" (`inplace=True`), создавая резервную копию файла (`backup=.extension`)

---

[Пример использования - реализация утилиты `grep` на Python](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch33s03.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, fileinput
pattern= re.compile( sys.argv[1] )
for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[2:]):
    if pattern.match( line ):
        print(fileinput.filename(), fileinput.filelineno(), line)
```

Comment: Да документацию то читал, я просил конкретный пример  из практики  системного администирования (в английском есть понятие use case).  Был просто удевлен, что об этом модуле так мало где написано, когда случаи работы с файлами рассматриваются. Хотя его поведение это 100% `cat` и чтение из `stdin`, что 99% ежедневной моей работы. Но спасибо за ваш ответ.

Comment: По-моему в примере `#` не хватает?

Comment: @nobody, спасибо, поправил :)